# How does "du balai" get to mean "go away"?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

I believe the expression "du balai" means literally "of the broom".

How did it acquire the meaning of "go away!" or "get lost!"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Du*** doesn't mean "of the" here but is closer to "some" in "give me some".

The ***balai*** is used as a metaphor. The person to whom ***du balai*** is addressed is asked to be swept out by this imaginary broom.

The expression seems to have first appeared by the end of the 19th century in the play "*Une opposition*" (In *Un Client sérieux*, 1897) by Georges Courteline, a famous writer of *Théâtre de boulevard*. Maybe Courteline created it or perhaps it was already used.

Comment: Wonderful!  Thank you!  What is your source for the expression's first appearance?  I ask because I expect this source to be the kind of reference resource I like to bookmark!