# How do you say the command “Away with you!” in French?

Tags: constructions

How do you say the command
[**“Away with you!”**](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/away-with-you) ?

I feel like this is a command someone from the aristocracy  would use in the past. With that in mind, what is the French equivalent? Thank you so much for your help guys!

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/away-with-you

https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/away-with

Comment: loin avec vous ou sois parti

Comment: @user716881 You are drinking deeply to the fountain of anglicisms in your contemplation of those forms as renderings for "Away with you!".

Answer (score 4):

A plain rendering is "**Allez-vous en** !". If spoken it must be pronounced with force, unless the context  is clearly one in which the hostility of the speaker is apparent. Given no special context, this can mean simply "Go away!", as when giving someone the advice to leave one place for their own good.

"**Hors de ma vue !**" conveys the displeasure  of the speaker, which can be great if the phrase is pronounced with force. This is then a preferred form to render "Away with you!", as this latter communicates no friendly feelings, at least usually.

There is also the colloquial "**Décampez !**" (**Décampe !** in the second person singular).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9camper)) B.− P. ext., fam. [Le suj. désigne une pers. ou un animal]
> 2. S'en aller au plus vite, s'enfuir précipitamment.

This could still be used in a formal context as it is not labelled "popular" (populaire), as for instance "**Foutez le camp !**".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/camp)) Pop., fam. Foutre, ficher le camp.

However, the verb "déguerpir" would be an option that is formal enough.

- **Déguerpissez !** — **Déguerpis !**

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer @LPH !

Answer (score 3):

You might say:

> *Allez, du vent !*

to keep the old fashioned aristocratic tone.

Some alternatives:

> [Ouste !](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Ouste)

> *[Du balai !](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/42225/how-does-du-balai-get-to-mean-go-away)*

> *Dehors !*

> *Hors de ma vue !*

Comment: Thank you so much! 

Comment: Aristocratiquement prononcé avec le flegme qui convient : « Veuillez reconduire définitivement Monsieur hors de ces murs », avec en plus un nuance d'agacement : « Vous êtes insupportable ! Je vous demande de vous en aller », avec un mépris définitif : « Je vous convie à partir, je dois me retirer de ce salon » ………